# compiling typescript file creates empty js file in vs code

Tags: typescript, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, compilation

I have installed vs code on ubuntu 20 and wanted to compile a .ts file via `tsc`
which created a empty js file.

node is installed , also typescript

also testing it with webstorm created a correct js file

why does this dont work in vs code ?

Answer (score 4):

You probably have not saved the file. Ctrl + s your .ts file and then run the tsc command in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not saved the file. Ctrl + s your .ts file and then run the tsc command in terminal. Its work for me.